# Apply a function to a set of .csv with similar names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I wish to apply a really simple function in `R`

```
BasicFun <- function(x) {
  c(min = min(x), max = max(x), 
    mean = mean(x))
}
```

To a specific column called "Values" always present in a set of `.csv` files, all with very similar names (`basedata10people.csv`, `basedata20people.csv`, etc...), these names follow:

```
seq(10, 300, by=10)
```

So I am looking to do something like:

```
names <- seq(10, 300, by=10)    
for (i in 1:names) {    
 {    
 file[[i]] = read.csv(file=paste("basedata", [[i]], "people", sep=""))    
 a=BasicFun(file[[i]]$Values)    
 results[[i]] = rbind(a)    
  }    
  allresults = rbindlist(results)    
  write.csv(allresults, file=paste("allresults.csv", sep=""))    
}
```

With the aim to compile all those results in a single `.csv`, that would look something like:

```
 file min max mean     
 10   30  80   52    
 20   27  89   60    
 30   25  91   50
```

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `names[[i]]` instead of `[[i]]`  Also, the `.csv` part is missing in the `paste` i.e. `read.csv(file = paste0("basedata", names[[i]], "people.csv"))` and the `for` loop would be `for(i in seq_along(names))`  assuming that `results` is initiated earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this without any loops.

First I set up some dummy data and put it in a folder:

```
list.files("~/Desktop/test_data")
[1] "basedata10people.csv"   "basedata20people.csv"   "basedata30people.csv" 
[4] "not_csv.txt"            "not_the_right_name.csv"
```

Next we only select the files you want:

```
list.files("~/Desktop/test_data", "basedata\\d+.*?.csv")
[1] "basedata10people.csv" "basedata20people.csv" "basedata30people.csv"
```

Then we set up a dataframe with the files, nest the data, and extract the desired values.

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(files = list.files("~/Desktop/test_data", "basedata\\d+.*?.csv")) %>%
    mutate(files = paste0("~/Desktop/test_data/", files),
        data = invoke_map(read_csv, files),
        min = map(data, ~min(.x$value)),
        max = map(data, ~max(.x$value)),
        mean = map(data, ~mean(.x$value))) %>%
    select(-data) %>%
    unnest()
#   files                                      min   max  mean
# 1 ~/Desktop/test_data/basedata10people.csv     2    51  17.8
# 2 ~/Desktop/test_data/basedata20people.csv     2    51  18  
# 3 ~/Desktop/test_data/basedata30people.csv     1   123  32.2
```

If you wanted to use your function, you could also do that.

```
data_frame(files = list.files("~/Desktop/test_data", "basedata\\d+.*?.csv")) %>%
    mutate(files = paste0("~/Desktop/test_data/", files),
        data = invoke_map(read_csv, files),
        vals = map(data, ~BasicFun(.x$value)))%>% 
    unnest(vals %>% map(broom::tidy)) %>% 
    spread(names, x)
#   files                                      max  mean   min
# 1 ~/Desktop/test_data/basedata10people.csv    51  17.8     2
# 2 ~/Desktop/test_data/basedata20people.csv    51  18       2
# 3 ~/Desktop/test_data/basedata30people.csv   123  32.2     1
```

UPDATE:

Here we change the file names to numbers

```
data_frame(files = list.files("~/Desktop/test_data", "basedata\\d+.*?.csv")) %>%
    mutate(files = paste0("~/Desktop/test_data/", files),
        data = invoke_map(read_csv, files),
        vals = map(data, ~BasicFun(.x$value)))%>% 
    unnest(vals %>% map(broom::tidy)) %>% 
    spread(names, x) %>%
    mutate(files = as.numeric(str_extract(files, "(?<=basedata)\\d+(?=people)")))
#   files max  mean   min
# 1 10    51  17.8     2
# 2 20    51  18       2
# 3 30   123  32.2     1
```

Comment: This works great, but the first column returns the full file name, how can I change it to return only the number that changes in each file (seq(10, 300, by=10)?    

Once I want to use those numbers to plot the mean against...

Comment: Yes, I'll update now. Instead of just numbering sequentially, I am going to extract the number out of the file name. This will take care of any issues if the files are not in the correct order.

Comment: That works brilliantly, thank you so much for your help.